# Ошибка в методе с dynamic параметром и возвращаемым значением?

Tags: c#

```
  class Program
{
    private static string[] array = new string[5];

    static dynamic Method(dynamic argument)
    {
        if(argument is string)
        {
            if (argument.Equals("array"))
            {
                return  array;
            }
            else { return 1; }
        }

    }

    static void Main()
    {
        string @string = Method("array");

        Console.WriteLine(@string);

        // Delay.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Почему пишет, что не все ветви кода возвращают значения? Ведь я использую retutrn .

Comment: код **должен быть текстом**, а не картинкой

Comment: Извините, но в данном случае вместе с ошибкой так нагляднее.

Comment: Вот, теперь код а не картинка, хотя я не считаю в данном случае это критичным - т.к была  видна сразу и ошибка. Ладно.

Comment: текст ошибки тоже надо добавлять в вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у первого if нет ветви else. вложенный возвращает в 2 случаях, а первый -нет